# How to use Stargazer R package with factor analysis output

Tags: r, stargazer

I've used stargazer in the past with regression tables.

However I'd like to know how to use stargazer with output from factor analysis and principal component analysis.

My code runs as follows:

```
fa1 <- factanal(new2, factors = 4, rotation = "varimax", sort = TRUE)
print(fa1, digits = 3, cutoff = .5, sort = TRUE)
load <- fa1$loadings[,1:2] 
plot(load,type="n")
text(load,labels=names(new2),cex=.7)
```

AND

```
two <- pca(new2, nfactors = 3)
```

THIS doesn't work - my only attempt so far.

```
stargazer(fa1, type = "text", title="Descriptive statistics", digits=1, out="table1.txt")
```

UPDATE: Since posting I have been able to convert the object to a data frame with:

converted <- as.data.frame(unclass(fa1$loadings))

I then used the code above successfully EXCEPT that the output doesn't seem to include individual factor scores.

See below:

[loadings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bflTP.png)

Answer (score 0):

this might not be a perfect sulution and you might have found out by now, but what you can do is to output the factor scores separately with stagazer by adding `summary = FALSE` as an option. This way you get only the factor loadings as an output.
For example like this:

```
stargazer(fa1, summary = FALSE, title="Descriptive statistics", digits=1, out="table1.txt")
```